# Getting different django administration title

Tags: python, django, documentation

I am trying to get a different header in django administration. I would like to put the company's name there instead. I am trying to do it through the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/

Near the bottem, it says to add a TEMPLATE_DIRS setting, which I did.

So, if I have:

```
 '/LPG/firstproject/firstproject/templates',
```

in my TEMPLATE_DIRS

and this is where the django source file of base_html is at
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/

What exactly does it mean when it says "Now copy the template admin/base_site.html from within the default Django admin template directory in the source code of Django itself"

Is this done with a command or how exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Inside your main template folder, create an `admin` folder. Inside it, create a file named `base_site.html` with the following content:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }} | {% trans 'Your Site Title' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
    <h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Your Site Title' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Basically, if you want to override a django admin template, you have to match the path for the template and then create your own custom template.